# Getting out of page

Tags: php, navbar

I have made a navbar in photoshop and converted into code using the Save to web function in Photoshop, now the navbar is getting displayed OK, but when I add other stuff code then it just gets out of the page, its width increases.

My navbar.html

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Couture Collection</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Untitled-3) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1366" height="78" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="images/navbar_01.png" width="1125" height="21" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/navbar_02.png" width="241" height="21" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/navbar_03.png" width="180" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/navbar_04.png" width="217" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/navbar_05.png" width="272" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/navbar_06.png" width="207" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/navbar_07.png" width="414" height="56" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/navbar_08.png" width="76" height="56" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="180" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="217" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="272" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="207" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="249" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="165" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="76" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your other stuff code? What goes out of the page? And what width increases? Please be more specific.

Comment: Every kind of code, even carousel code makes it get out of the page, even  if the carousel is small and in the middle, the navbar gets out of page

Comment: I attached the navbar to my index.php using include 'navbar.html',  and I added the carousel code in the index.php

Comment: You should use CSS instead of Inline-Attributes and work with relative Widths instead of fixed ones.

Answer (score 0):

`1125+241 = 1366` and `180+217+272+207+414+76 = 1366`

So if you add another `td` it will increase your nav and exceed 1366px. Best way should be to use real HTML + CSS to make your navbar instead of generating it with photoshop because it's using fixed `width` (which is not responsive at all)